# Roman numeration in an xlist environment

Tags: numbering, lists, linguistics, gb4e

How do I set an xlist environment inside an exe environment to use lowercase roman numeration? It always defaults to lowercase letters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where are the `xlist` and `exe` environment defined?

Comment: Are you using `gb4e`?

Comment: Yes I'm using gb4e

Comment: @ydnfmew: You'll have to be more forthcoming. Please provide code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: You got two excellent answers here. What prevents you from accepting one of them?

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) it is difficult to be sure, but I think that you just need to redefine `\thexnumii`, which you can do with:

```
 \renewcommand\thexnumii{\roman{xnumii}}
```

Of course, if you are going to nest these further then you should also redefine `\thexnumiii` etc. Doing this you get the output

[image]

from the MWE (which is adapted from the [gb4e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\renewcommand\thexnumii{\roman{xnumii}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{exe}                   % sets up the top-level example environment
    \ex\label{here} Here is one.  % example with running number
    \ex[*]{Here another is.}      % judged ex. with running number
    \ex Here are some with judgements.
     \begin{xlist}                % first embedding (alphabetical numbering)
     \ex[]{A grammatical sentence am I.}
     \ex[*]{An ungrammatical sentence is you.}
     \ex[??]{A dubious sentence is she.}
     \ex                          % just the number
     \ex Dare to judge me!
     \end{xlist}                  % end first embedding
    \ex This concludes our demonstration.
  \end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gb4e` package comes with variants of the `xlist` lists:

[image]

So there's no need to change the format of the `xnumii` counter manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlisti}
\ex An example.
\ex Another example.
\end{xlisti}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want to do this globally for all instances of `xlist`, and you are only using one level of `xlist` in the document, you could simply add

```
\let\xlist\xlisti
```

to your preamble.